# Is there a way to filter an excel while resetting the row numbers so it goes from 1,2,3 etc... to the end?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Pretty much, when I currently filter an excel workbook (like normally), the row numbers can be from 1, 4, 5, 10 etc and jump around. I want to be able to filter an excel workbook but after filtering, it will still be 1,2,3 etc with the other filtered out content hidden and not affecting the row numbers. The reason I am doing this is that afterwards, I want to use VBA to run some formulas and it would be easier if I filter it as so rather than pasting the filtered data over since it is so big. Does anyone have any ideas? VBA/ Excel formula step suggestions both will be great.

Comment: [Filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) if you've got 365.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

G2 ↓

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(F$1,,,ROW()))-1
```